Assigning a variable with a static name to the value of another variable that has a dynamic name
I have different lists (list_<string1>, list_<string2>, etc...), so <stringx> is a dynamic name in this context.
I know what is the current dynamic name in my workflow (I named it 'category' in my example below), and I want to create a new variable 'list_traits' that is equals to list_<category>. Below is a minimal example.
list_dynamicname = ['a','b','c']

category = 'dynamicname'
x = 'list_traits = list_' + category
print(x)
exec(x)

print(list_traits)

And here is the output:
list_traits = list_dynamicname
    print(list_traits)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^
UnboundLocalError: cannot access local variable 'list_traits' where it is not associated with a value

Also, if I try the function that should never be used, here is what I get:
eval(x)

    list_traits = list_dynamicname
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

What am I doing wrong here ?
I have looked at other posts, but mostly it was about assigning a value to a variable with a dynamic name, but in my case, my new variable has a static name (by this I mean it will always be list_traits), and I try to assign to it the value of a dynamic variable.

You shouldn't have these individual lists in the first place.  Use a list (or dict) of lists, so that you can use ordinary indexing to select one of them.

exec is also an eval – never use it for normal code.

That's what I read from other posts: using dictionary. I will try and update the post with a solution. But out of curiosity, why my current syntax does not work? I understand eval or exec are to be avoided, but I do not see my error.

I cannot reproduce, you are probably doing this inside a function, please always provide a [mcve]

You can achieve the same functionality without using exec, which is generally discouraged due to potential security risks and performance issues. Instead, you can use a dictionary to map your category names to their corresponding lists.
lists = {
    'dynamicname': ['a', 'b', 'c']
}

category = 'dynamicname'
list_traits = lists[category]

print(list_traits)

